# Creating simple WPF window takes very long

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a very simple program. I have a Window with the following .xaml code

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow">
</Window>
```

and the following code behind

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window {
    public MainWindow(uint width, uint height) {
        InitializeComponent();
        Width = width;
        Height = height;
    }
}
```

In my main class I just start the Application

```
public class MainClass {
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        Application app = new Application();
        app.Run(new MainWindow(600, 600));
    }
}
```

When I run the program, it takes up to 5 seconds to show the window. How can that be?

**EDIT**

I just reproduced it in a new project. If I remove `Width = width;` and `Height = height;` it's not as slow. Why is this?

Comment: Why not simply set the Width and Height in the XAML

Comment: @Monty: Usually I am calculating the width and height of my window before but to make my example as small as possible I added a default size.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: @EldarDordzhiev: I just reproduced it in a new project. Did you do it exactly like I did? Did you add the `Width = width;` and `Height = height;` lines? I found out those lines are the reason for it being so slow.  I wonder why.

Comment: @gartenriese Yep, these lines as well. The only difference is that I declared `Main()` in `MainWindow`, not in a separate class.

Comment: @EldarDordzhiev: Okay, something is seriously wrong on my end. I just created a new WPF project and ran it without adding anything and the window creation took at least 2 seconds.

Comment: @gartenriese That is probably the debugging starting time. Starting the project without debugging (Ctrl+F5) must show you a window instantly.

Comment: It is clear that it may some time to run your app on debug mode. I guess it runs immediately when executed directly (i.e. not via VS). Or, starting debugging takes much longer than before?

Comment: @dytori: I found out that NVIDIA 3D Vision is at fault. I uninstalled it and it works fine now.